# subfig: subrefformat not doing anything

Tags: formatting, captions, subfig

I would like to format my subfigure labels as **A**, **B**, ... in the caption of the figure using `\protect\subref{...}`.

Consider the following:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\DeclareSubrefFormat{mybold}{\textbf{#2}}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=mybold}

\begin{document}

See \cref{fig:1a}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat{\label{fig:1a}}
    \subfloat{\label{fig:1b}}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{
        \protect\subref{fig:1a} First sub caption.
        \protect\subref{fig:1b} Second sub caption. 
        And some more text
    }
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which outputs:
[image]

I.e. despite

```tex
\DeclareSubrefFormat{mybold}{\textbf{#2}}
\captionsetup{subrefformat=mybold}
```

the labels are neither bold, nor without parentheses. Yet,

```tex
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
```

did work.

What is going on? Is it because of `\protect`? What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You need to use `\subref*` for boldface to appear and also to use the appropriate option to `\captionsetup`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
\DeclareSubrefFormat{mybold}{\textbf{#2}}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{subrefformat=mybold}

\begin{document}

See \cref{fig:1a}

\begin{figure}
    \subfloat{\label{fig:1a}}
    \subfloat{\label{fig:1b}}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{
        \protect\subref*{fig:1a} First sub caption.
        \protect\subref*{fig:1b} Second sub caption.
        And some more text
    }
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Silly me... Thanks a lot!